# How to pass path parameter which has "/" in it in URL?

Tags: rest, url, postman

My URL looks like this
`https://example.com/organization/org-codes/{orgCodes}/partnership-type/{partnershipType}/app-code/{appCode}/partnership-facilities`

The value of partnershipType is : "LTL/Parcel Motor carrier" (without double quotes)

After URL encoding it looks like this:
`https://example.com/organization/org-codes/AXN/partnership-type/LTL%2FParcel%20Motor%20carrier/app-code/MSR/partnership-facilities`

But this is giving 400 Bad Request error for some reason.

Please help me with this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does your server's error log tell you about this?

Comment: You'll probably need to configure your server to allow encoded slashes in the path; most servers don't allow that by default for security reasons.